# Copy url and paste in chrome toolbar in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, automated-tests

Im trying to test that i can use a copy URL button, open a new window and paste the url. Currently i cant seem to work out how to do it. This is my code so far, the copy_url button basically copies the url:

```
    copy_url_button.click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Drivers.getDriver(), 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(link_copied_text_element));
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> 
    (Drivers.getDriver().getWindowHandles());
    Drivers.getDriver().switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

Comment: What does `copy_url_button.click();` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use something like this:

```
void openInNewTab(WebDriver driver, String url) {
  String script = String.format("window.open('%s');", url); 
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script); 
}
```

Comment: Sure, but where am i getting the url from? Where does the copied url come from?

Comment: i.e. `String link = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your_selector"))
        .getAttribute("href");`

Comment: I don't know the HTML you work with, so I cannot help with your issue =(